# How can I change the exposure of an sRGB image?

Tags: post-processing, srgb, exposure

I wish to "normalize" the exposure of a set of images before doing further processing.  I tried the following:
1) convert sRGB to CIE_XYZ per Wikipedia page on sRGB;
2) multiply or divide "Y" by 2 to achieve a 1 stop EV change;
3) convert CIE_XYZ back to sRGB.
The problem is that step 3 frequently yields negative values (they arise after matrix multiplication to convert back to linear rgb).
In particular, my test set of sRGB values have the form (n,n,n) where 0<=n<=255.
I would expect these to be near the center of the gamut, and that a 1 stop change would not push me out of the gamut.
What is wrong with this approach??

Comment: I think you might need xyY color space

Comment: Chris H:  "Y" of XYZ and xyY are the same, aren't they?.  I am changing only Y.  How would doing so in xyY space result in different sRGB values than changing Y by the same amount in XYZ?

Comment: according to https://ninedegreesbelow.com/photography/xyz-rgb.html

In the XYZ color space, Y corresponds to relative luminance; Y also carries color information related to the eye's "M" (yellow-green) cone response. X and Z carry additional information about how the cones in the human eye respond to light waves of varying frequencies.

...

 Unlike XYZ, xyY space cleanly separates the XYZ Y (luminance) from color, or rather from chromaticity, which is what the "xy" in xyY stands for.

Comment: Just linearize RGB, change the stop and reapply gamma.

Comment: While Giacomo's idea is similar to what I first thought, I suspect this does not work well near the extremes - highlights or darks - since in those regions raw->rgb conversion may apply non-linearity that makes the response curve look more like an "S", with flattened shoulder and toe.  What is your opinion???

Answer (score 0):

I believe that user:1146345's comment is the most accurate, in that it refers to the non-linearity introduced by the raw->rgb conversion.  So, for example, conversion from sRGB -> linear RGB -> multiply by 2^(delta stops) -> sRGB will not work well near the ends of the curve.   But we don't know how to characterize this non-linearity, since it most likely varies by camera.

Answer (score 0):

## There Are Good Linear Image Apps

Using an application such as *Adobe AfterEffects*, converting to linear is trivial, and most of the tools you need remain available. Unfortunately, Photoshop's implementation of 32bit float linear is less functional.

Nevertheless, once in 32bit floating-point linear space (gamma 1.0), then all the linear math you do functions like light in the real world. In the Film/TV industry, we work in linear most of the time, if not in AfterEffects, then Nuke or Fusion, etc.

Human perception is NOT linear however — so while linear math on linearized image data will behave the way light does, it won't be relative to perception. If you want to use linear math to affect perception in a linear way, then you need to be in a perceptually uniform colorspace such as CIELAB.

Let's assume though that you want to change photometric "exposure", then you want to affect light values as they would be affected in the real world, and so you need to linearize your image data. AE has tools to help here - you'd first set your project to 32 bit floating point, and then select an appropriate profile and "linearize". Make sure you turn ON display color management.

When you import an image, use the appropriate profile to "unwind" it into linear space.

If not using AE, but using MatLab or Octave, then apply the sRGB transfer curve (aka gamma) to unwind the image into linear space.

## S Curves etc.

I see some of the comments regarding cameras/debayering algorithms adding S curves aka "soft clip" at the high or low ends. Going to CIEXYZ is not going to help this, and only adds unneeded matrix math.

#### Stay in sRGB

You will typically be fine to just linearize the sRGB, and stay in linearRGB for your various manipulations. If you ae scaling luminance by 2, then you are probably going to want to be adjusting the high clip anyway - any soft clip is just going to be scaled along with the rest of the image, and that is really not an issue, so long as you are in 32bit floating point, then you won't have any significant quantization errors, and you can adjust the S curves after exposure.

If you want you can use "Curves" to adjust/expand the high end. AE though also has a built in ImageRAW importer, so you can import directly from RAW and set it to not compress highlights.

If you don't have access to the RAW and only the JPG, then again, it should be fine so long as you are in linear 32 bit. After all your manipulations, just re-apply the gamma curve, and the original S curves will remain intact relative to the image highlight, which is usually what you want.

#### Plug Ins and Gamma

Note that AE and PS and others do have "exposure" plug-ins that can affect this change.

**BUT ALSO:**

Keep in mind that if you are wanting to emulate real film, that each of the color records has a different gamma, and in film they do interact more than the digital values in sRGB which essentially remain separate.

If you are trying to emulate a film look, try using the LEVELS plugin and playing with the gamma/hi/lo of each color channel separately. Or do the same using CUVES.